# Why must I invoke ghostscript directly to convert PS to PDF?

Tags: ghostscript, ps2pdf

My computer runs on Windows 7 with  MikTeX 2.9 and GhostScript 9.02 installed.

I am still confused why do I have to invoke `gswin64c.exe`
rather than `ps2pdf.exe` to convert ps to pdf?

The switches I want to use are

```
 -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=filename.pdf -c save pop -f filename.ps
```

When I use `ps2pdf.exe` with the switch above, it got error message as follows.

[image]

Experiment results based on Philippe's comment as follows.

### Not working syntax:

- `ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 in.ps out.pdf`
- `ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE#a4 in.ps`

### Working syntax:

- `ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE#a4 in.ps out.pdf`
- `ps2pdf in.ps out.pdf` with top margin gets cropped.
- `ps2pdf in.ps` with top margin gets cropped.

Comment: What is the error message? Which distribution and OS do you use?

Comment: I am no longer interested in this question because I have migrated to TeX Live 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use `gswin64c` directly. `ps2pdf` should work. And it does work for me. (TeX Live 2011)

On the other hand, `ps2pdf` command is actually a script (`ps2pdf.exe` in TeX Live calls a Lua script `ps2pdf.tlu`) which calling GhostScript, say, `gswin32c.exe` or `gswin64c.exe`.

> `Usage: ps2pdf [options] (input.[e]ps|-) [output.pdf]`

However, the option you use does fails. `-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite` are defined in `ps2pdf` script, you don't need them. `-sOutputFile` can also be replaced. It's safe if you use them, however.

I'm not sure what `-c save pop` mean. It seems that this option cause the problem. Without this option, everything is Okey.

Comment: I tried `ps2pdf.exe -sPAPERSIZE=a4 foo.ps` and it works. There may be something wrong with your TeX distribution or GhostScript. I'm not sure.

Comment: @xport: under Windows, you usually have to replace the `=` sign by a `#` e.g. `ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE#a4 filename.ps`

Comment: @xport: No. It's only a bit complex.

Comment: @xport: try also with `ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE#a4 filename.ps filename.pdf`. Do you still have the `Unknown paper size: ().` error? What error do you have when you just use `ps2pdf filename.ps filename.pdf`? Have you updated you MikTeX recently? (If it's a bug, it might be fixed.)

Comment: @xport: glad it worked. `ps2pdf` under Windows is really touchy about syntax.

Comment: @xport: I don't know, all my tries with `-c save pop` have not been working. I'm not sure what it does. The ghostscript manual says it executes the postscript code `save pop` but I have no idea what that does. It is mentioned on http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/bugs28.htm related to font bounding box errors.